# Facebook login with Laravel 5

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a login via facebook to a laravel 5 based application.
I read [This social authentication explanation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication).

```
  [1]: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication
```

I added this to my routes:

```
   Route::get('facebook-login', 'FacebookLogin@redirectToProvider');
```

I added this to the controllers folder, file name :FacebookLogin.php

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    class FacebookLogin{
    public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialize::with('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialize::with('facebook')->user();

    // $user->token;



dd($user);
}

}
```

Now when i go to:

```
http://localhost:8000/facebook-login
```

This is the message that i get:

```
FatalErrorException in ControllerDispatcher.php line 201:
Call to undefined method App\Http\Controllers\FacebookLogin::getAfterFilters()
```

Does anyone have any insight?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where is called this (getAfterFilters ) method ?

Comment: If only I knew...
Not anything that comes from MY code.

Comment: Take a look here http://tutsnare.com/social-authentication-in-laravel-5/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your FacebookLogin does not extend Controller (or BaseController in laravel 4).
Try

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class FacebookLogin extends Controller 
{
//Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This was one of the issues but i also didn't save my composer file, so updating the composer didn't work...